# ADB2C User Flow and IEF policies not interoperable?

Tags: azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-webapi, azure-ad-b2c

I have a .NET WebApi app project which has been using the built in User Flow policies. These policies are being replaced with the new ones from IEF.

What I am finding is that if I generate a token from an IEF policy but try to use it on a WebAPI which is default setup to use a UserFlow policy, it fails as the signature doesn’t match.

Example of the WebApi app settings

```
"AzureAdB2C": {
    "Instance": "https://XXXXX.b2clogin.com/tfp/",
    "ClientId": "XXXXX",
    "Domain": "XXX.onmicrosoft.com",
    "SignUpSignInPolicyId": "B2C_1_signinsignup" //UserFlow policy
    "SignUpSignInPolicyId": "B2C_1A_CustomSigninAndSignUp" //IEF policy
  },
```

As the UserFlow and IEF policies are on the same tenant, I would have thought they would be interchangeable/interoperable? It works if I set the WebApi to use one of the IEF policies.

Is a way to make the UserFlow and IEF policies work together?

Comment: "set the WebApi to use one of the IEF policies"    Can it be expressed in more detail? How was this step done?

Comment: How did you generate tokens from the IEF strategy? Can you provide the code?

Comment: Basically if I do a File>New WebAPI project and select Individual Accounts, you can enter the tenant name, client ID and the only 1 policy for "SignUpSignInPolicyId". If you use a User flow policy here for example, but the token you pass in to it is generated from an IEF policy (same tenant), you get a signature fail mismatch error. I generated the IEF tokens using the getting started guide https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-get-started?tabs=applications

Answer (score 1):

@Raj,

Different policies have their own signatures and cannot be used for each other unless you disable the signature verification in .net.

If you look at the OpenID metadata for each policy you will notice in the keys element that each has a different signature and will not validate for other policies.

https://flirb2cdev.b2clogin.com/flirb2cdev.onmicrosoft.com//v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration

Comment: Ive had a look at these OpenID docs for my Userflow and IEF policies and none contain a signature? (They both mention id_token_signing_alg_values_supported = RS256).

Comment: For my webapp integration, I used https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnetcore-webapp which has since been archived and replaced with the newer UI integration libraries. However, this seems to work fine without any disabling of signatures, so I am a little lost here.

Comment: In Azure Active Directory B2C, custom policies are designed primarily to address complex scenarios. For most scenarios, the recommendation is to use built-in user flows.

Comment: That comment offers no real help in this case :)

Answer (score 1):

From what i understand of this, when you create a custom policy (IEF) part of the setup requires you to create/add signing and encryption keys: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-get-started?tabs=applications#add-signing-and-encryption-keys

so if you created a bunch of custom policies, you could import the same signing / enc keys to make all of the custom policies work with same token.

in theory if you could download the signing/enc keys that the built-in policies use (user flow), then you could import them into the custom policies and in theory they should match and validate. However, since the user flows (built-in) policies are actually inherited from microsoft's tenant and uses microsoft public/private keys, i don't think there is a way to extract those. 
this means, probably not possible to have both ief and userflow policies validating to the same key signatures. 
the only remaining solution if you need both policies would be to ignore validation as per Christopher's suggestion, but that is not highly recommended.. as the validation is there for a reason.. so it would be a security risk.

Comment: If this is the case, this really needs clarifying on the Microsoft docs. I think a lot of people would start with User Flows and migrate to IEF, so knowing the gotchas would be good.